# Can one single application connect with multiple Firebase Account?

Tags: android, ios, firebase

We want to implement the Firebase Analytics, Remote Config, and A/B Testing for our application (android/ios). However the problem is we are currently using vendor solution for our push notification that using Firebase too. So our application already connected with their Firebase Console account. However, the vendor won't give the access for Firebase Console Account.

It is possible to connect to two or more Firebase Account at the same time?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A single application can connect to multiple Firebase projects. See the [Firebase documentation on configuring multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/) for details, specifically the section on [accessing multiple projects in a single app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application).